# What does 'knowing from' mean?

Tags: meaning

***know A from B*** means ***distinguish A from B***. But what does intransitive ***know from*** mean? I looked it up in several dictionaries to no avail.

> Not only architects are researching architectural subjects. A lot of
> researchers come from other disciplines with different research
> cultures. Hence, research approaches as well as research achievements
> are different. They are published in journals of each discipline,
> often not ***knowing from*** each other; some are not even published,
> as they were done in offices and not labeled as research.

[Research Culture in Architecture: Cross-Disciplinary Collaboration](https://books.google.co.kr/books?id=zbHQDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT10&lpg=PT10&dq=The%20design%20process%20refers%20to%20many%20involved%20disciplines%20such%20as%20construction,%20materials%20science,%20building%20physics,%20manufacturing%20technology,%20computer%20science,%20geometry,%20aesthetics,%20sociology,%20philosophy,%20and%20history.&source=bl&ots=4Y9aU9I8mu&sig=ACfU3U2qy9TWPkDA6lqe56jXssdLoZAScA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjNx8XPvfb2AhXCGaYKHcezBV4Q6AF6BAgCEAM#v=onepage&q=The%20design%20process%20refers%20to%20many%20involved%20disciplines%20such%20as%20construction%2C%20materials%20science%2C%20building%20physics%2C%20manufacturing%20technology%2C%20computer%20science%2C%20geometry%2C%20aesthetics%2C%20sociology%2C%20philosophy%2C%20and%20history.&f=false)

Answer (score 4):

In that sentence it appears to simply mean 'not knowing about.' As a native speaker with an West Coast American dialect, it sounds weird here, and I don't think it is a common usage.

Comment: It sounds like strange cross between *without hearing from each other*, and *without knowing about each others work.*